# Regular Expression Pattern which should not allow ,;:|

Tags: regex

I need the regular expression pattern which should not allow  to put any of following characters into input in HTML

```
,;:|
```

Comment: what you tried? how it failed? what are example of your input? we are not here to write code for you, but to help you learn how to code yourself

Comment: You also didn't mention the target language for the regular expression (if the test is done on server-side)

Answer (score 1):

You may get some idea from this.

```
[^,;:|]+
```

DEMO:::  https://rubular.com/r/dKQzC1HrnMG88X

Comment: Thanks everyone for  your reply. I got it regex pattern. Sorry this is my first question  in stackoverflow.

Comment: @purushotham, please update the answer. It's may help someone.thanks.